# Webpack configuration with lerna and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import, lerna

I have a fairly complex project with the following structure:

```
bundles/
  one/
    webpack.config.js
  two/
    webpack.config.js
packages/
  a/
    src/
    lib/
    tsconfig.json
  b/
    src/
    lib/
    tsconfig.json
```

Inside the `a` and `b` packages I would prefer to be able absolute paths, relative to the package. In other words if a file inside `a` needs to import another file inside `a` it should look like

```js
import 'mod1` from 'common/mod1';
```

rathern than

```js
import 'mod1` from '../../common/mod1';
```

I found this to work nicely by adding a `rootDir` and `baseUrl` to the package `tsconfig.json` file

```json
"compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "baseUrl": "src"
       }
    }
```

Unfortunately when webpack tries to bundle the packages together, it fails.

I've seen that it's also possible to define things differently using the path option in `tsconfig.json`. In this case the file would look like:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
          "~/*": [
            "./*"
        ]
       }
    }
```

and it would be possible to import a file doing

```js
import 'mod1` from '~/common/mod1';
```

Again typescript succeeds but webpack seems to fail.

I've tried to add this configuration to my `webpack.config.js` but they don't seem to help

```js
config.resolve.alias = {
    "~/": './../../packages/a/lib/',
};
config.resolve.extensions = ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx'];
```

I feel like what I'm trying to do should be possible. Is there anything misconfigured? How can I fix webpack?